# Is it possible to convert CHARACTER to INT

Tags: sql, excel, casting, openedge, progress-db

I have a dataset which currently the Event Time `(trovalue)` is in a `CHARACTER` format. I need to be able to convert these to an `INTERGER` so i can `SUM` these on import so i am able to `GROUP` the data.

Currently i have tried to do the following which is returning an error of invalid number string (7498):

```
CAST (TemplateRunObject_0.TroValue AS INT)
```

I am working from a Progress OpenEdge ODBC and pulling directly into Excel.

What is the best way to convert `CHARACTER` to `INTERGER`

Comment: Perhaps you have a value which is not a number, that's why it gives you error.

Comment: You could use a `CASE` statement together with the `ISNUMERIC()` function to only perform the aforementioned `SUM` action only when the value is a number.

Comment: It sounds pretty clear to me that you have data in that `TroValue` field that can't be cast to an integer.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the time is stored as "18:53:21" or something of that ilk. So the : is throwing off the CAST(). But without a data example we're all just guessing.